# Do you say "She has been closing her eyes for 1 hour" or "Her eyes have been closed for 1 hour"?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, phrase-usage, phrase-choice

Is "**to close her eyes**" a one-off action or a prolong one?

I think there are some verbs used to express some actions that can not be prolonged.

For example, "**I have been finishing the homework for 1 hour**" because when you finish it, it just happens right away.

When we say "**she closes her eyes**", it's hard to say but I think "**She has been closing her eyes for 1 hour**" sounds wrong because that closing-eyes action only takes about 1 sec to complete it.

Do you say "**She has been closing her eyes for 1 hour**" or "**Her eyes have been closed for 1 hour**"?

And "**She is closing her eyes now so I don't see them**" or "**Her eyes are closed now so I don't see them**"?

Answer (score 1):

You're right that *close one's eyes* is punctual, and you wouldn't normally use it in a progressive form.
But your two sentences differ in animacy. While

> Her eyes have been closed for an hour.

is perfectly good, if you want to bring the sleeper into it, you can say

> She has had her eyes closed for an hour.

But you are wrong about *finish*. While intransitive *finish* is punctual (eg *the meeting finished*), transitive *finish* need not be: *to finish my homework* often means "doing the last part of my homework", and might be a continuing process. So

> I have been finishing my homework for an hour.

is OK; but you would not use it if you have in fact done the whole of your homework in that hour: it implies that at the start of the hour, you believed you were close to the end.